# I dont know how to connect SQLite with c++ on visual studio

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

im begginer as a sql programmer. I want to make my first app with data base. SQLite seems to be the best for me but i have no idea how it works. I have done what is written here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm but dont know what next. i downloaded the first one from here where are 2 files .h and 2 files .c .I suppose that i have to use it somehow, because i need to include SQLite in visual studio but dont know how

Comment: Put those 2 files into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the sqlite files into your project (that is in solution explorer right click on the project node and select Add->Existing files and then select the files, they should be copied into the project directory), you can then #include the header file and use sqlite calls from your own source.

Comment: Which files? .h?